# Orthonormalization with a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

In my lecture notes we have a $n \times p$ block matrix
$$
Y =
\begin{pmatrix}
  I_p \\
  Q
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and it is orthonormalized in the following way:
$$
\hat{Y} =
\begin{pmatrix}
  I_p \\
  Q
\end{pmatrix}
\left(I + Q^*Q\right)^{-1/2}.
$$
I can not see how the matrix on the right orthonormalizes neither do I know how to handle the inverse square root. Can someone elaborate? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, when you say that we're "orthonormalizing" the matrix $Y$, you mean that the columns of $\hat Y$ will be an orthonormal basis for the column space of $Y$.  I think our only assumption on $Q$ is that it is $(n-p)\times p$.

First, the $-1/2$: note that for any positive semidefinite matrix $A$, there exists a unique positive semidefinite square root $A^{1/2}$.  If $A$ is invertible (positive definite), then we may find the inverse of this square root, namely $A^{-1/2}$.  Notably, $A^{1/2}$ (and $A^{-1/2}$) necessarily commute with $A$.

To see that the columns of $\hat Y$ are orthonormal, it suffices to note that $(\hat Y)^* \hat Y  = I$.  Indeed, we have:
$$
(\hat Y)^* \hat Y =  [(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}]^* \pmatrix{I&Q^*}\pmatrix{I\\Q}(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}
\\ = 
(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}(I + Q^*Q)(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}
\\ = 
(I + Q^*Q)(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}(I + Q^*Q)^{-1/2}
\\ = 
(I + Q^*Q)(I + Q^*Q)^{-1} = I
$$
To see that the column space of $\hat Y$ is identical to that of $Y$, it suffices to note that $\hat Y = YM$ for an invertible matrix $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!